# Unicode characters causing issues in SQL Server 2005 string comparison

Tags: sql-server, unicode, collation, string-comparison

This query:

```
select *
from op.tag
where tag = 'fussball'
```

Returns a result which has a tag column value of "fußball".  Column "tag" is defined as nvarchar(150).

While I understand they are [similar words grammatically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fussball), can anyone explain and defend this behavior?  I assume it is related to the same collation settings which allow you to change case sensitivity on a column/table, but who would want this behavior?  A unique constraint on the column also causes failure on inserts of one value when the other exists due to a constraint violation.  How do I turn this off?

Follow-up bonus point question.  Explain why this query does not return any rows:

```
select 1 
where 'fußball' = 'fussball'
```

Bonus question (answer?):  @ScottCher pointed out to me privately that this is due to the string literal "fussball" being treated as a varchar.  This query DOES return a result:

```
select 1 
where 'fußball' = cast('fussball' as nvarchar)
```

But then again, this one does not:

```
select 1 
where cast('fußball' as varchar) = cast('fussball' as varchar)
```

I'm confused.

Comment: what collation do you use on your SQL Server? What language and locale settings are you using?

Comment: @marc_s everything is default US installation.  I think that's Latin1_General_CS_AS?

Comment: @marc_s default collation is set to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.  Perhaps this server was upgraded from Sql Server 2000.  Still confused about this behavior though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the Unicode collation set for your connection/table/database specifies that ss == ß. The latter behavior would be because it's on a faulty fast path, or maybe it does a binary comparison, or maybe you're not passing in the ß in the right encoding (I agree it's stupid).

http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/#Searching mentions that U+00DF is special-cased.  Here's an insightful excerpt:

> Language-sensitive searching and
>   matching are closely related to
>   collation. Strings that compare as
>   equal at some strength level are those
>   that should be matched when doing
>   language-sensitive matching. For
>   example, at a primary strength, "ß"
>   would match against "ss" according to
>   the UCA, and "aa" would match "å" in a
>   Danish tailoring of the UCA.

Comment: Thanks!  I edited to make a more direct link, and quote a relevant section of the article.

Answer (score 3):

The SELECT *does* return a row with collation Latin1_General_CI_AS (SQL2000).

It does *not* with collation Latin1_General_BIN.

You can assign a table column a collation by using the COLLATE < collation > keyword after N/VARCHAR.

You can also compare strings with a specific collation using the syntax

```
string1 = string2 COLLATE < collation >
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer that explains behavior, but may be relevant:

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187112/write-a-t-sql-query-that-filters-records-containing-nchar2028) question, I learned that using the collation of

```
Latin1_General_Bin
```

will avoid most collation quirks.

Answer (score 1):

Some helper answers - not the complete one to your question, but still maybe helpful:

If you try:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE N'fußball' = N'fussball'
```

you'll get "1" - when using the "N" to signify Unicode, the two strings are considered the same - why that's the case, I don't know (yet).

To find the **default collation** for a server, use

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation')
```

To find the **collation of a given column** in a database, use this query:

```
SELECT
  name 'Column Name', 
  OBJECT_NAME(object_id) 'Table Name', 
  collation_name
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_ID = object_ID('your-table-name') 
AND name = 'your-column-name'
```

Answer (score 1):

> Bonus question (answer?): @ScottCher
>   pointed out to me privately that this
>   is due to the string literal
>   "fussball" being treated as a varchar.
>   This query DOES return a result:
>
> `select 1   where 'fußball' =`
>   `cast('fussball' as nvarchar)`

Here you're dealing with the SQL Server data type precedence rules, as stated in [Data Type Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx). Comparisons are done always using the higher precedence type:

> When an operator combines two
>   expressions of different data types,
>   the rules for data type precedence
>   specify that the data type with the
>   lower precedence is converted to the
>   data type with the higher precedence.

Since nvarchar has a higher precedence than varchar, the comparison in your example will occur suing the nvarchar type, so it's really exactly the same as `select 1  where N'fußball' =N'fussball'` (ie. using Unicode types). I hope this also makes it clear why your last case doesn't return any row.