# Entity Framework 4: SQL to Linq: How to select strings that are not uppercase?

Tags: linq, sql-server-2005, entity-framework-4

This SQL selects all names that are not uppercase:

```
select name
from   myTable
where  not (UPPER(name) = name collate Latin1_General_BIN )
```

How would you do the same think in Linq (Entity Framework 4?)

Edit:

Both `String.Compare` and string = string resolve to SQL of `UPPER(name) = name` which is case insensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pure LINQ, but you could use ExecuteQuery, eg

```
 string sql = @"
     select id , name 
     from   myTable
     where  not (UPPER(name) = name collate Latin1_General_BIN )
  ";

var results = 
   (from r in dc.ExecuteQuery<myTable>(sql) 
    select  new { r.Name } 
   ).ToList();
```

Note, you need to include id in the query, even if you only want name.

Comment: That worked. TYVM.  I will have to do a custom class for <myTable> and add all the necessities like skip and take to the SQL statement as it will try to grab all the records locally otherwise.  Very cool.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly understand what you're trying to achieve.

Entity Framework and ADO.NET in general, have different patterns than SQL server.
If you want to stick to the syntax in your query, create a Stored-Procedures or a UDF and port it to EF.

I tried to perform it with LINQ and I didn't find a way, since EF SQL generation for LINQ is case-insensitive!
So I guess you'll have to do it with a UDF or a SPROC.

UPDATE:

I must leave now, but I think this post might help you:
[Unicode characters causing issues in SQL Server 2005 string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275782/unicode-characters-causing-issues-in-sql-server-2005-string-comparison)

Comment: SPs, views, etc. are nice, but require added complexity. Your code resolves to 
SELECT [t0].[Title] 
FROM [context] AS [t0] 
WHERE [t0].[Title] = UPPER([t0].[Title]) which doesn't do a case sensitive search.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ToUpper() method to convert a string to upper case, e.g.

```
entities.Where(x => x.Name != x.Name.ToUpper()).Select(x => x.Name)
```

Obviously you should consider whether you need to supply a particular `CultureInfo` to the `ToUpper()` method and whether you want to do a culture specific comparison instead of using the `!=` operator.

Comment: The problem is without collate Latin1_General_BIN, the comparisons are not case sensitive. Your code produces
SELECT [t0].[Name] AS [Name] 
FROM [entities] AS [t0] 
WHERE [t0].[Name] = UPPER([t0].[Name]) 
which selects all items regardless of case.  I am definitely looking in to the culture specific comparisons, which might be the answer.

Comment: aha of course - I keep forgetting about case insensitivity on the SQL side (I'm a little out of touch with SQL server these days!) - I'd be very interested to know if you manage to find a way to use CultureInfo to force the required operation in the SQL. Clearly sgmoore's answer works, but it has the downside of requiring explicit SQL manipulation.