# Create a model from the result of sql statement with entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

In the current environment I am working on, I was confronted with a not very trustful database. Where I have, among all the shannannigans, tables without keys, fields in wrong sizes, very bad separation and relation in tables, and et cettera.
Well, they asked me to make a query in that database, and I can't create a view for such. Nor I have writing access what-so-ever to such DB.
Is it possible to use Entity to parse the result of a query and populate a list of that model?

I know how to do it with nhibernate, and manually, but, is it possible to do it in EF?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to put the `SELECT` you would have put in your view right into the ExecuteQuery as described in [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660697/entity-framework-4-sql-to-linq-how-to-select-strings-that-are-not-uppercase) and do your data validation like you want.

Comment: That is exactly what I've needed! Thanks